# is it possible to find the meta data of a song using its ISRC

Tags: gracenote

I was wondering if it was possible to find the meta data of a song(genre, era , tempo, mood) using its ISRC via the mobile SDK or the web api? I know the web api support text search but It looks like it is not very accurate f you do not have the exact artist name and song title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to search using ISRC. 
You can get ISRC returned with the search result, but not the other way around.

Comment: that is what I was my impression but I thought I will still ask.Thanks for the prompt reply :)